# Copying dynamic array causes Subscript out of range error

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to copy worksheets from a master workbook to a target workbook but the sheets that I copy are different depending on if the value in rngCurrent is present in the worksheet name. For some reason I keep getting a subscript out or range error on the last line. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

```
Sub test2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim master As Workbook
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim wbAdjustments As Workbook
Dim wsName As Worksheet
Dim rngEntityList As Range
Dim rngCurrentEntity As Range
Dim rngCurrent As Range
Dim arrWorksheets As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim wsCount As Integer

Set master = ThisWorkbook


Set rngCurrentEntity = master.Sheets("File Info").Range("rng_Entity") 'named range of single entity

Set rngEntityList = master.Sheets("Global").Range("rng_EntityList") 'list or entities

Set rngCurrent = rngEntityList.Find(rngCurrentEntity.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) ' find single entity in the list

If rngCurrent.Offset(, 4).Value = "FRP" Then 'find if it's FRP
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Foreign.xlsx")

Else
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Domestic.xlsx")

End If

Dim ws() As String ' declare string array
ReDim ws(wb.Worksheets.Count) As String ' set size dynamically

Dim counter As Long ' running counter for ws array
counter = 1



For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
    If InStr(1, wb.Worksheets(i).Name, rngCurrent.Value) <> 0 Then
        ws(counter) = wb.Worksheets(i).Name
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve ws(counter) As String ' Get rid of empty array entries

    wb.Worksheets(ws).Copy After:=master.Worksheets(master.Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```

**EDIT** 
The reason I need to do it this way is because I don't want the external links to the source notebook.

Comment: what line are you getting your error?

Comment: By default the lower bound of an array is zero, not one.  Your error is from there being no content in the 0'th slot in your array.  Try `ReDim ws(1 to wb.Worksheets.Count)` (specifying both the upper and lower bounds, without the `As String`)

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm getting the error on the wb.Worksheets(ws).Copy line

Comment: @TimWilliams I just tried that and now the `ReDim Preserve` line is throwing the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the `As String` ?  `ReDim Preserve ws(1 to counter)`  Also - start counter at zero and increment it *before* adding the sheet name to the array.  Right now if you only added one sheet then counter ends up at  2...

Comment: @TimWilliams I removed the `As String` from both spots. I moved the `counter = counter + 1` to increment before adding the sheet name  and started it at 0 instead of 1. I still get the error at the `ReDim Preserve` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete and tested example

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook, i As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws() As String ' declare string array
    ReDim ws(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count) As String ' set size dynamically

    Dim counter As Long ' running counter for ws array
    counter = 0

    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If InStr(1, wb.Worksheets(i).Name, "test") <> 0 Then
            counter = counter + 1
            ws(counter) = wb.Worksheets(i).Name
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve ws(1 To counter)

    wb.Worksheets(ws).Copy 'just makes a copy in a new workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just about to post that I got it figured out. Thanks! I would've never thought about updating the counter first.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
ReDim ws(1 To wb.Worksheets.count) As String ' set size dynamically, start from 1
Dim counter As Long ' running counter for ws array

For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count
    If InStr(1, wb.Worksheets(i).name, rngCurrent.Value) <> 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1 '<--| update counter
        ws(counter) = wb.Worksheets(i).name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's giving me an error at the `ReDim Preserve` line now.

Comment: the redim must be `ReDim Preserve ws(1 To counter) As String`